# Problems with read.csv.sql when data has commas

Tags: r, sqldf, read.csv

I'm trying to read a .csv file like the following:

"Name", "Address"
"Me", "My address, City, State"

When I try

```
read.csv.sql(file = "myFile.csv", sql = "select * from file")
```

I get an error:

```
Error in .local(conn, name, value, ...) :   
  RS_sqlite_import: myFile.csv line 2 expected 2 columns of data but found 4
```

It seems like read.csv.sql is unable to recognize that the address record in my .csv file is one observation (rather than 3, given the commas).  Is there any way to avoid this problem?  I looked at the help file for read.csv.sql, but it doesn't seem like there's an option that fixes this issue.

In reality, I have a large file and I want to only read a subset of the columns.  If there is another tool available within R, I'm happy to use that instead of read.csv.sql.

Comment: Does adding `quote = "\"'"` help?

Comment: @Jaap Unfortunately no; it seems that quote is not an argument to read.csv.sql.

Comment: This is handled by using the `filter=` argument. This is discussed (i) in `?read.csv.sql` , (ii) in the `file.format` argument documentation of `sqldf` and (iii) in example 13 in the sqldf README shown at the bottom of the home page: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf